# pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode

Tags: pdftex, pdf, compiling

On compiling a tex file the following error message appears

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode
```

No pdf is generated and a blank gray display appears. How to fix this issue?

Comment: That's not an error message. It's the command your computer is trying to run. Can you tell us what software you are using to edit your .tex file and what distribution of TeX you have installed?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using TeXstudio 3.0.1 with TeX Live. Is that what you asked?

Comment: Yes. My guess is that TeXstudio can't 'see' the compiler for some reason. Try opening a windows command prompt and entering `pdflatex --version`. What is the result?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?